# Undefined Control Sequence,Missing $ and Display math should end with $$

Tags: math-mode, equations

I am trying to write the below equation and keep getting the various below errors.

1. Undefined control sequence
2. Missing `$` inserted
3. Display math should end with `$$`

I don't really understand the problem with my code. FYI...this is the code

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eqn: current}
$I_{FS} = \sum_{\substack{i}}*\frac{1}{2}*\frac{W}{L}*(V_{gs}-V_{th})^2*(1+\lambdaV_{ds})=\frac{1}{2}*k*(V_{gs}-V_{th})^2*(1+\lambda*V_{ds})*\sum_{\substack{i}}*\frac{W}{L}$
\end{equation}
```

I have tried putting `\equation` also doesn't work. Previous to that, I used simple `$...$` also, still useless.

Would be glad if someone can point out the error and give me a fix for this issue as I am a new user to LaTeX.

Comment: Multiplication is usually not denoted with `*`; also `\substack{i}` can be just `i`: `\substack` is necessary only for multiline subscripts.

Answer (score 5):

use

```
\begin{equation}\label{eqn: current}
I_{FS} = \sum_{\substack{i}}*\frac{1}{2}*\frac{W}{L}*(V_{gs}-V_{th})^2*(1+\lambdaV_{ds})=\frac{1}{2}*k*(V_{gs}-V_{th})^2*(1+\lambda*V_{ds})*\sum_{\substack{i}}*\frac{W}{L}
\end{equation}
```

without the `$ ...$` They are only for inline math mode, see http://mirror.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf

Answer (score 5):

"Undefined control sequence" error messages are always followed by a line that ends with the problem control sequence. It is important to include that information in your question. I will guess that it is `\lambdaV`. You need to separate `\lambda` and `V` with a space or some non-letter character.

All The other errors are because of the `$`s at the start and end. The `equation` environment puts you in math mode already. Don't use those extra dollar signs, they just confuse LateX. The following should compile without error (though there are typographical problems with it):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eqn: current}
  I_{FS} = \sum_{\substack{i}} * \frac{1}{2} * \frac{W}{L} *
  (V_{gs}-V_{th})^2 * (1 + \lambda V_{ds}) = \frac{1}{2} * k *
  (V_{gs}-V_{th})^2 * (1+\lambda*V_{ds}) * \sum_{\substack{i}} * \frac{W}{L}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

(I've broken the lines and added some spaces for readability, but it is the same as your equation.) The `\sum` symbols seem not to be actual sums, perhaps you wanted `\Sigma`? The `*` are very seldom used in math for multiplication. The `\substack` command is for stacking one line on top of another in a subscript. I has no effect on a single symbol except to misposition it. Removing the `*`s and the `\substack`s it becomes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eqn: current}
  I_{FS} = \sum_{i} \frac{1}{2} \frac{W}{L}
  (V_{gs} - V_{th})^2 (1 + \lambda V_{ds}) = \frac{1}{2} k
  (V_{gs} - V_{th})^2 (1+\lambda V_{ds}) \sum_{i} \frac{W}{L}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This equation might also benefit from being placed in an `align` environment, with a line break before the second `=` symbol and alignment done on the two equal symbols.

Comment: @Mico Yes, but I was trying to take small steps. The most important points were: (1) explain the error messages (and how to correctly report one); (2) remove things that were incorrect, though didn't produce errors, except in appearence. Improving appearence and exposition is several steps down the list.

Comment: Sorry if I came across as overbearing. Your reworking of the original posting is a major improvement.